# getting a long list from grep -l -- is it possible?

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I'm performing this grep:
grep -l "Validation failed" *.dbg

This returns a file listing. However, I'm most interested in the times modified of these files.

What would the proper command be?

Edit: the argument in the title was wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

xargs is my friend, apparently.
The answer is:
grep -l "Validation failed" *.dbg | xargs ls -ltr

Comment: If you have GNU userland (e.g., GNU/Linux system), a more robust solution (which handles filenames with whitespace characters) is: grep -lZ "..." *.dbg | xargs -0 ls -ltr

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with

```
for file in `grep -l "Validation failed" *.dbg`; do ls -ltr $file; done
```

but xargs is definitely neater, shorter, and gives you easy delimiter options.

Comment: Not only is xargs neater & shorter, your solution will fail for file names with spaces in them (it will split them at the spaces). xargs -0 handles that.